# Android SQLite ContentValues put() method parameters

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just got started with learning Android's SQLite. So I'm trying to inspect each of the methods and classes used.

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
public static final String DB_TABLE = "myTable";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String LNAME  = "LNAME";
public static final String FNAME  = "FNAME";
public static final String GENDER = "GENDER";
public static final String COURSE = "COURSE";


public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBHelper (Context aContext){
            super(aContext,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LNAME TEXT, FNAME TEXT, GENDER TEXT, COURSE TEXT) " );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DB_NAME );
        }
    }


public long Employee(String aLastName, String aFirstName, String aGender, String aCourse ){
        open(); //opens the database
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); //creates instance of ContentValues class to store  values
        cv.put(LNAME,aLastName); // put(key,value) method is used to assign the parameters to its destination column in the database
        cv.put(FNAME,aFirstName); //put(key,value) 
        cv.put(GENDER,aGender);
        cv.put(COURSE,aCourse);
        return myDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE,null,cv);
    }
```

Does `key` in `put(key,value)` have to match the exact column name in the database?

From what I read the `ContentValues` class is used to store data to the database.

I'd appreciate any explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `key` is the column name in the database, and `value` is the value to store in that column.